# Function and class on the same file: undefined function

Tags: php, namespaces, psr-0

I have a file with a class and a function definition, according to the [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) definitions (with autoloading):

```
namespace Foo;

function b() {};

class Bar {}
```

And I have the test for that class, place in the same namespace:

```
namespace Foo;

class BarTest {}
```

When I try to access the `b()` function inside the test class, I get a `undefined function` error:

```
namespace Foo;

class BarTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSomething()
    {
        b();
        Foo\b();
        \b();
    }
}
```

Nothing seems to work. How can I call that function?

Comment: Did you include the file that contains `b` and `Bar`? It might be that you've got some autoloading that will not include the file with `Bar` until you use that class.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `testSomething()`         
`b();
        Foo\b();
        \b();`

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I edited the question with autoloading info.

Comment: So? Try calling `new Bar()` before `b`, does that work?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen it does work if I instantiate the object first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP autoloading does not support functions. However it does work for *static* class methods:

```
namespace Foo;

abstract class Util
{
    static function doSomething() {

    }
}
```

You can then `use` that class in some other files current namespace and call the static method:

```
use Foo\Util;

Util::doSomething();
```

As this is a class method and autoloading is for classes, this does work then.

Take care that the more correct way to group methods inside a namespace / class is probably making it [*`final`<sup>Docs</sup>*](http://php.net/language.oop5.final) as well, however PHP does not support that (see [*Cannot create a final abstract class<sup>­PHP Sadness #41</sup>*](http://phpsadness.com/sad/41)).

You find this as well outlined in the following Q&A Material here on the site:

- [Autoloader for functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737199/autoloader-for-functions) - Jan 19 '11
- [autoload functions in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196881/autoload-functions-in-php) - Nov 16 '10
- [Does the PHP autoloader function also work with static method calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044514/does-the-php-autoloader-function-also-work-with-static-method-calls) - Jan 11 '10

Answer (score 0):

Your function b(); must have body, change it to

`function b(){};`

Comment: Actually it does have a body. It was a typo.

Comment: Please look at this @drgomesp http://codepad.viper-7.com/e5Momf

Comment: The thing is, I wanna call the `b()` function from outside, and not have a wrapper method inside the object of that class.

Comment: hmm interesting question, guess I have understand the problem such it is.. http://codepad.viper-7.com/3WMaFY

Comment: Except I don't want to use the `b()` function inside the class itself, but always outside. I just want to declare the class inside that namespace and that particular file.